# Javascript Functions True or False

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hello I have this function:

```
function makeTweet(params) {
    var tweetID = params.tweetID;
    var tweetDate = params.tweetUrl;
    var tweetText = params.tweetText;
    var tweetUrl = params.tweetUrl;
    var authorName = params.tweetDate;
    var authorNickname = params.authorNickname;
    var authorAvatar = params.authorAvatar;

    if ( haveOauth() == true ) {
        alert("We have the account, make the reply");
    }else{
        alert("We do not have it");
    }
}
```

It should get the results of the below function and understand if it returns true or false and do a certain action based on that.

How do I do it? Whatever I do now, returns the same result.
Something is wrong here.
Thanks

```
function haveOauth() {
    var user_id = "1";
    var data = $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "uspolitics_pulse/functions.php",
        data: { type: 'checkOauth', user_id: user_id },
        async: false,
        success : function(data) {
            if(data) {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }); 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`async: false` is never recommended, but you could try replacing

```
if(data) {
   return false;
}
```

with

```
var result = false;
var data = $.ajax({
    // ...
    success : function(data) {
        result = data;
    }
}); 
return result;
```

But why not have `haveOath` take its own callback

```
function haveOauth(callback) {
    var user_id = "1";
    var data = $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "uspolitics_pulse/functions.php",
        data: { type: 'checkOauth', user_id: user_id },
        success : function(data) {
             callback(data);
        }
    }); 
}
```

And then

```
function makeTweet(params) {
    var tweetID = params.tweetID;
    var tweetDate = params.tweetUrl;
    var tweetText = params.tweetText;
    var tweetUrl = params.tweetUrl;
    var authorName = params.tweetDate;
    var authorNickname = params.authorNickname;
    var authorAvatar = params.authorAvatar;

    haveOauth(function(data) { 
        if (data) {
           alert("We have the account, make the reply");
        }else{
            alert("We do not have it");
        }
     });
}
```

Comment: no it's the below function that should return false or true. Not the first one, the second function.

Comment: See in the second function where it says: if(data) {
return false;
}

Comment: @DiegoP.: The return will happen instantly, you can't return the result value of an asynchronous request (which may result in an error). But, you can return a [promise](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Futures_and_promises) object.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function haveOauth() {
    var result = true;
    var user_id = "1";
    var data = $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "uspolitics_pulse/functions.php",
        data: { type: 'checkOauth', user_id: user_id },
        async: false,
        success : function(data) {
            if(data) {
                result = false;
            }
        }
    }); 

    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Similar to Michael Swan's answer - in that I don't think you can ever reach a situation where you return true.

```
function haveOauth() {
var user_id = "1";
var data = $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "uspolitics_pulse/functions.php",
    data: { type: 'checkOauth', user_id: user_id },
    async: false,
    success : function(data) {
        if(data) {
            return false;
        }
    }
});
return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The function `haveOauth` includes an AJAX call which is not recommended to be synchronous, as @AdamRackis pointed out. (Apart from that, your `return` inside the callback function passed to `$.ajax` does not do what you want, and you're missing a `return true` somewhere – see the solution by @MichaelSwan.)

You could make your code asynchronous using a callback that gets passed the result of the check in `haveOauth`:

```
function haveOauth(callback) {
    var user_id = "1";
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "uspolitics_pulse/functions.php",
        data: { type: 'checkOauth', user_id: user_id },
        success : function(data) {
            if (data) { // or whatever check needs to be made
                callback(true);  // signal that authenticated
            } else
                callback(false); // signal that not authenticated
        }
    }); 
}
```

And then use that function like this in `makeTweet`:

```
haveOauth(function(isAuthenticated) {
    if (isAuthenticated)
        alert("We have the account, make the reply");
    else
        alert("We do not have it");
});
```